Book recommendation for Analysis 2
For my analysis 2 course, I want an undergraduate textbook which covers multivariable integral calculus, manifolds and differential form. Something similar to spivak's calculus on manifolds or pugh's book or rudin.
Any other book  which is nice and covers similar theory? The reason I  don't particularly like the way they develop the theory. They don't give much examples either.

Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres is often given as a more accessible alternative to Spivak.

@Stefan thank you. It looks nice.
